# Issue with RegularExpression validation using JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, jquery-plugins

I wanted to restrict the user from entering the values from a specific range. So i wrote the following code using JQuery 1.7.1

```
var reg = /^[0-9]{1,4}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}$/g;

$("#txt" + filterID).bind('keypress', function (e) {
    var nn = $("#txtValues");
    var strValue = nn[0].value.toString();
    strValue = $.trim(strValue);
    var bool = reg.test(strValue);
    if (strValue.length == 0 && !((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (bool) {
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

When i test the input box, it's not working as expected. It supposed to allow a floating point number with 2 digits after decimal point.Some of the valid formats are

> 1
>    1.
>    1.0
>    0
>    1.20
>    0.0
>    1.23
>    123.43
>    1234.12

I am not sure, where I have done wrong. After recognizing 1. it's getting failed.  Can anybody help me to identify the issue?

Comment: What is not working as expected? The numbers you name here valid are exactly those you define in your regex.

Comment: Do you require that there is a fraction and that it has two digits?

Comment: When i test the textbox in HTML form, It's allowing '1.',  then it's not allowing any other digit, which it supposed to allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keypress` event is fired before the value has updated. Use the following code, which translates the `event.which` property to a character using the `String.fromCharCode` method.

Non-printable keystrokes will generate a `event.which` of zero, which is certainly not a digit or dot.

As for the RegExp, you have to group the expression after the dot, and add a questionmark, to say "Let this group match be optional".

```
var reg = /^[0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/;

$("#txt" + filterID).bind('keypress', function (e) {
    var nn = $("#txtValues");
    var strValue = nn[0].value.toString() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    strValue = $.trim(strValue);
    var bool = reg.test(strValue);
    if (bool) {
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The pattern will match the following:

```
1
1234
1234.5
But not:
1235.    (Change {0,2} to {1,2} if you want to reject this match)
123456
1234.567
```

Answer (score 0):

The interval operators in your expression `{0,1}` and `{0,2}` allow for a group to be repeated 0 to 1, or respectively 0 to 2 times, which allows for decimal numbers as well as integers. Also you should specify the literal dot `\.` instead of just the dot, which matches any character.
If you want to enforce numbers with 2 digits after the decimal, try restricting your interval to {2} and bundle it into a group together with the dot, e.g.
`/^[0-9]{1,4}(\.{1}[0-9]{2})$/`

Comment: A dot inside a character class `[.]` matches a dot, not any character.